# Why are this monopole and dipole antenna so similar?

Tags: antenna, ground-plane, dipole

I opened two different GSM antenna housings as shown on the images.

The first image shows the [RF SOLUTIONS  ANT-GHEL2R-SMA](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1696741.pdf) antenna, which is an helical 1/4 wave monopole antenna.

The second image is the [SIRETTA  DELTA2C/X/SMAM/S/RA/25](http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1877150.pdf), which is, according to its datasheet, a dipole antenna.

My question is why do they look so similar except for the shape of the copper? I would expect a dipole antenna to actually show two poles. Does the connector housing act as the other pole? If so then why is the monopole not a dipole as well?

[image]
[image]

Comment: *"My question is why do they look so similar except for the shape of the copper?"* What other difference IS there?

Comment: Well, as far as I'm concerned, they're both quarter wave monopoles. Provide links to the sources of the information please. Oops you did!

Comment: they are both monopoles of some kind

Comment: One is top-loaded, the other bottom-loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you see **+2dBi gain**, and the manufacturer has fairly measured gain to be 2dB above an isotropic radiator, then the antenna is more complex than a simple quarter-wave monopole. I would hesitate to guess exactly how the pig-tail top of the upper photo monopole attains its gain.
A simple half-wave dipole might have intrinsic gain near +2dBi. The one pictured in the bottom photo appears to be end-fed half-wavelength antenna with a low-Z to high-Z matching section buried in the connector shell. Arranged as shown, it would be vertically polarized...an end-fed dipole, rather than a centre-fed dipole.

Comment: You wrote both comments so that even I can follow their logic! Thanks!

Comment: Sounds good +1 for the info.